# Maven Deployment Parameters in pom.xml

Tags: java, git, maven, deployment, github

I have a Maven project which should deploy their compiled files in another folder. Currently, i am doing this by specifying the parameter `altDeploymentRepository`:

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:/home/user/some/folder/mvn-repo/snapshots deploy
```

My question: Is it possible to do a simple `mvn deploy` instead and move the parameter declaration to the pom.xml instead? If yes, how?

### Update

I get asked why i want to do this. I have separated my project into the Maven project with the sources and the Maven repository. Both are different Github projects and therefore in different folders. I configured Maven so that the target files are deployed in the repo folder. After that i just need to git add, commit and push the changes.

If there is any way to push the target files directly to the desired Github repo with `maven deploy` or to make this procedure more straightforward, i am all ears!

Comment: The question is: Why?

Comment: I updated it to answer your question.

Comment: The answer to "why" is simple - if you want to de-couple your testing cycles and you only want to deploy to a proper repository after all tests pass.    It's a common problem.   Sometimes I want to run a build and unit test only.  More time-consuming testing cycles are deliberately de-coupled.  This is a core Continuous Delivery best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was easier than expected. I needed to add a configuration block to my plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <altDeploymentRepository>
                  snapshot-repo::default::file:/home/user/some/folder/mvn-repo/snapshots
                </altDeploymentRepository>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-wagon</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-svn-wagon</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure you actually understand the meaning of "deploy" in Maven, coz it is quite weird to "deploy to other folder" as what you are doing.

Maven Deploy means deploying the artifact to remote repository.  Remote repository is where Maven search for artifacts and download to local repository.  It is seldom "another folder".  We normally use `<distributionManagement>` to configure the remote repository to deploy.  Normally we used `altDeploymentRepository` to deploy to a different remote repo as configured in `distrubutionManagement`.

If you simply want to put your built artifact to a separate folder, which is not aimed for a "remote repository", I believe assembly (or similar plugin) is what you need.

Comment: I updated my question, maybe there is something else you can recommend.

Comment: I am still not quite understand your problem after your update.  Do you mean you have a separate Git repo storing the build result (the EARs)?  If so, in brief, you are simply not using Maven right.  And, that's not a Maven repository.  I'd strongly recommend you to get a Maven repo (e.g. Nexus) and use it.  In Maven, one very basic point is, we don't keep the built artifact/dependencies etc in version control, because it is just not right/necessary to store artifacts in version control system.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the above answer, it is possible to isolate builds from deployments by initially deploying to a file system repo under the target folder as part of your build, then using the wagon plugin to sync up your local (and private) staging-repository to a more public repository.

Apologies up-front that this is *nix based (see `pwd`)

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=local-staged-repo::default::file://`pwd`/target/staged-repo \
    clean \
    deploy
```

Alternatively, it can be coded inside your pom.xml like so:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <altDeploymentRepository>
        staged-repo::default::file:${project.basedir}/target/staged-repo
      </altDeploymentRepository>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
    ...
```

Then at a later stage, run from your project's root folder.  You can merge your staged-repo inside the target folder of your root pom.xml to a more permanent repository using the following plugin:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-5:merge-maven-repos \
  -Dwagon.source=file://`pwd`/target/staged-repo \ 
  -Dwagon.target=http://<some-repo>/release \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
```